# How to enable VESA framebuffer as default in NetBSD 6.1

Tags: kernel, netbsd, framebuffer

When booting NetBSD, the old Tecra 720CDT that I have, works quite nicely in 1024x768x15 mode with vesa fb.

I always have to activate VESA when booting the system:

```
> vesa on
> vesa 0x116
> boot netbsd
```

Now, I was able to somewhat automatize this process by editing `/boot.cfg`:

```
menu=Boot normally:rndseed /var/db/entropy-file;vesa on;vesa 0x116;boot netbsd
```

No idea if this is preferable. I'd actually like to set this kind of behavior in the kernel itself. on OpenBSD, I'd simply use `config` to change the kernel settings. That, however, does not work on NetBSD. I'd have to recompile the kernel (that's my understanding).

Now, when looking through the config file, I couldn't find things related to vesa or switching to framebuffer mode while booting. Is this even possible? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, editing /boot.cfg is the preferred method.  You can even specify more human-readable modes; I am using (on -current, 7.99 in a VirtualBox VM)

```
menu=Boot normally:rndseed /var/db/entropy-file:;vesa 1024x768x32; boot netbsd
```

I think having this in the kernel somehow without it being compiled in would be bad - if you update your kernel you'd lose the setting.  The /boot.cfg method is persistent and human-readable.

Comment: where is this /boot.cfg  file located ? You mean /boot/grub2/boot.cfg or /boot/grub/boot.lst ?

Comment: No, /boot.cfg is only there if you're using the NetBSD bootloader. I don't offhand know how to set the mode using Grub.